# in Ruby, trying to convert those weird quotes into "regular" quotes

Tags: ruby, text, string

I am trying to parse a text file that has the weird quotes like
“ and ” into "normal quotes like "

I tried this:

```
text.gsub!("“",'"')
text.gsub!("”",'"')
```

but when it's done, they are still there and show up as

```
\x93 and \x94
```

so I tried adding that too with no luck:

```
text.gsub!('\\x93', '"')
text.gsub!('\\x94', '"')
```

The problem is, when I try to show those weird quotes on a webpage, it makes that weird diamond with a question mark symbol: �

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work:

```
text = "“foo”"
=> "\342\200\234foo\342\200\235"
irb(main):002:0> text.gsub!("“",'"')
=> "\"foo\342\200\235"
irb(main):003:0> text.gsub!("”",'"')
=> "\"foo\""
```

You need to use a hex editor to figure out all the character codes involved.

Answer (score 0):

Re: the second question of why the weird quotes show on a web page as the � symbol:

Your problem is that your web page is not in UTF-8 mode. To get it there, see 
http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

If you can't change your web server, add a meta line in the head section of your web pages: http://www.utf-8.com/

Larry

Answer (score 0):

Your first gsubs should work. The reason the second set of gsubs don't work is that you're using single quotes and double backslash. Try the other way around:

```
text.gsub!("\x93", '"')
text.gsub!("\x94", '"')
```

You can also do this in one line:

```
text.gsub!("\x93", '"').gsub!("\x94", '"')
# or
text.gsub!(/(\x93|\x94)/, '"')
```

Are you sure the encoding of the string is correct?

Comment: When I try this or the other given answer, I get Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)